# "Username or Password incorrect" Even though I use the correct email and password?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can not log in to my Minecraft account. I have had the account for a few years now and have never had this problem. The unfortunate part is that I have never been able to log in the website, because I am asked security questions that I never had to set. However, now I am unable to even log into my account to play the game. I know that I am using the correct username and password. I put in the email used as opposed to my username, the same way that I have logged in since I got the account, I can log into my younger brothers account without a problem. I was just wondering if anyone else had the same problem I am having, and if anyone knew how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Mojang's support?

Comment: Like @DJ said, Mojang is the only one that can help you here. As we are not Mojang, we cannot help. We can only guess at what the peoblem is.

Comment: Be aware that Mojang servers will ban your IP after few bad tries (like 4-5), for some time (sometimes even 24hours!) , so trying it again and again is really not good idea. Then even correct login won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Either contact mojang or check your email address. Once you check your email find the Minecraft/mojang email and click on change password then change it to the password to what you want. Then try again. Hope this helps and have fun in Minecraft! :D

Answer (score -1):

When logging in to a minecraft account you **use your email** not your minecraft name.. That was changed a handful of years ago but still seems to mess tons of people up